# Why the difference between stat and df

Tags: linux, disk-usage, stat

I run these commands:

```
df /
stat -fc '%f * %s' /
```

and get

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ma....Vol00      26409212  15604380   9441888  63% /
```

and

```
2701196 * 4096 (which is 11064201216)
```

So df says 9,44 GB free and stat says 11,06 GB free
That is quite a difference. Why is stat giving a larger value? Who should I trust?

Comment: See [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311) Look at the part about "reserved". `echo "$(((26409212 - 15604380) * 1024))"`

Comment: See also [Why is (free\_space + used\_space) != total\_size in df?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/25602) or [Why is df missing 500MB of available space?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/220967)

Comment: Ah, when using
stat -fc '%a * %s' /  I get almost identical results (differs a few MB, not a few GB)